# Leveling the image with the Camera filter in ios 9

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage, ios-camera

I'm creating app for ios, I'm currently working in camera.I like to draw the balance or straightening the image with a filter, the balance filter should move along the angle of the phone to ensure the phone is in prefect straight. I imported the GPUImage for creating filters.I would like to share the image of the filter which I need the same to done in my project.
[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El8yB.png)

Comment: What are your questions?

Comment: @EITomato-Thanks for your reply. I'm a new bee, I want a leveling to be append on my camera preview.The purpose of this filter is to ensure the phone is in correct angle.This filter is used in VSCO cam app

Comment: @EITomato - can I achieve this with gryoscope? I need the line to be append on my camera to find in which angle my phone is titled.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `CMMotionManager` to get accelerometer data, which will tell you the angle of the phone. Use that angle to apply a transform to your `UIView`.